# how to click on element using WebDriver

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver

i need to click on dat element:

```
<span id="act_action9" class="" onclick="openDialog('export', event)">
    text
</span>
```

i cant click on id,because it is dynamic. After a click i am getting window with some settings.

Comment: Well what else have you tried? Show us more of the surrounding HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You should use xpath in order to click this element, so you could add an expression that unequivocally identify this element.

Could you please include more HTML code, because just with the code included is not enough to create a xpath expression.

I recommend this tutorial to start doing good xpath expressions:
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

Answer (score 0):

See example for dynamic xpath

`By.xpath("//span[@id [contains(.,'act_action')]]")`

Great xpath cheatsheets: http://extract-web-data.com/5-best-xpath-cheat-sheets-and-quick-references/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use xpath like following(assuming only digit is dynamic):

```
".//span[contains(@id, 'act_action')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

As ID is dynamic, you can use xpath for text which is inside span.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='text']").click();
```

Or if part of ID remain common, then you can use

```
//span[contains(@id,'act')]
```